# Prevented person names (database)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, user-input

So I have a website (using PHP, Mysql and PDO) where person must join with their real name (first and last name). Because I want to disallow some names so I created a db table "bannedpersonnames"
where columns are: id, firstname, lastname
They (names) can both be NULL.

NULL means that name can be anything

If I want to ban all persons named "Justin Bieber" one of the rows in table is

> Justin | Bieber

If person "Mark Bieber" now tries to join, his name is allowed because firstname does'nt match.

but if I want to ban **all persons who has last name Bieber** then one of the rows will be

> NULL | Bieber.

some examples:

**Table content:**

```
Justin | Bieber
NULL | Timberlake
```

- "Justin Example", Allowed
- "Justin Timberlake", Disallowed, last name is banned
- "Example Timberlake", Disallowed, last name is still banned
- "Justin Bieber", Disallowed, entire name is banned

So my questions are; is there a better way to do this and how? Of course this doesn't solve all name problems... I need a MySQL-code

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: This is a fruitless exercise. You will annoy people with names that will match - and they may be real. They may turn out to be good customers. So UserX (no name here) what is a valid name?

Comment: "Bieber" is not an entirely uncommon name.

Comment: So not only I am named Justin Bieber, I cannot even log in on your service. It is aptly said that *it never rains, but it always pours*. (Granted that not being able to log in somewhere comes a very poor second after being named Justin Bieber).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this logic does what you want.  It returns any matching "banned persons", if any:

```
select bp.*
from BannedPersons bp
where (bp.firstname is null or bp.firstname = $firstname) and
      (bp.lastname is null or bp.lastname = $lastname);
```

Comment: The whole concept is silly. There will be genuine people that will be in that banded list. For example some people are called "John Smith" and that is used in Hotels to be anonymous. But some people are  called "John Smith"

Comment: @EdHeal . . . That seems more like a comment on the question than on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this I would suggest looking at triggers.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

You could implement a trigger that fires on every insert to your user table, checking if a name is prevented by some logic.